# Объединение массивов с уникальным ключом

Tags: php, массивы

```
$arr1 = [
    ['id' => 133, 'mode' => 'auto', 'sum' => 14224],
    ['id' => 135, 'mode' => 'default', 'sum' => 43788]
];

$arr2 = [
    ['id' => 133, 'desc' => 'NF', 'alt' => 'NF lix'],
    ['id' => 135, 'desc' => 'DC', 'alt' => 'DC gix']
];
```

Имеются два массива, как их преобразовать так, что, если в обоих массивах совпадают `id`, то перенести все данные из 2 массива в первый, чтобы в результате получился такой вид:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [id] => 133
    [mode] => auto
    [sum] => 14224
    [desc] => NF
    [alt] => NF lix
)
```

Comment: Копайте в сторону `array_merge` . http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение:

```
$arr1 = [
    ['id' => 133, 'mode' => 'auto', 'sum' => 14224],
    ['id' => 135, 'mode' => 'default', 'sum' => 43788]
];

$arr2 = [
    ['id' => 133, 'desc' => 'NF', 'alt' => 'NF lix'],
    ['id' => 135, 'desc' => 'DC', 'alt' => 'DC gix']
];

$tmp = array_combine(array_column($arr2, 'id'), $arr2);

$result = array_map(function ($item) use ($tmp) {
    return (isset($tmp[$item['id']])) ? array_merge($item, $tmp[$item['id']]) : $item;
}, $arr1);

print_r($result);
```

В результате получаем:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 133
            [mode] => auto
            [sum] => 14224
            [desc] => NF
            [alt] => NF lix
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 135
            [mode] => default
            [sum] => 43788
            [desc] => DC
            [alt] => DC gix
        )

)
```

Comment: это то что нужно, даже кода минимум. благодарю!

Comment: @user299341 минимум кода не всегда хорошо, надо знать как что работает :) Пример на `foreach` будет быстрей... Хоть смотрится красиво, но надо чтобы было и эффективно

Comment: @Manitikyl, как проверить скорость?

Comment: @user299341 та в обычном `for` с миллион иттерациями запустить. и посмотреть что быстрее.

Comment: хотя нет, я передумал. `foreach` forever!

Answer (score 0):

[**Пользуйтесь оператором + объединения массивов**.](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.array.php)

```
$arr1 = [
    ['id' => 133, 'mode' => 'auto', 'sum' => 14224],
    ['id' => 135, 'mode' => 'default', 'sum' => 43788]
];

$arr2 = [
    ['id' => 133, 'desc' => 'NF', 'alt' => 'NF lix'],
    ['id' => 135, 'desc' => 'DC', 'alt' => 'DC gix']
];

$res1 = $arr1[0] + $arr1[1];
$res2 = $arr2[0] + $arr2[1];

$result = $res1 + $res2;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю про этот оператор, вы правы, требуется array_merge

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = [
    ['id' => 133, 'mode' => 'auto', 'sum' => 14224],
    ['id' => 135, 'mode' => 'default', 'sum' => 43788]
];

$arr2 = [
    ['id' => 133, 'desc' => 'NF', 'alt' => 'NF lix'],
    ['id' => 135, 'desc' => 'DC', 'alt' => 'DC gix']
];

// arr3 - для лучшего поиска, будем хранить ссылочки второго массива
$arr3 = [];
foreach ($arr2 as $value) {
    $arr3[$value['id']] = $value;
}


// Собсна перебор
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($arr3[$value['id']])) {
        $arr1[$key] = array_merge($value, $arr3[$value['id']]);
    }
}
var_dump($arr1);
```

Comment: А я то думаю, ну кто-то ведь должен с циклом выложить) голос

Comment: спасибо, не могли бы рассказать что значит &$value?

Comment: @user299341 ссылка, чтобы память зря не тратить, мы `$arr3[0] = &$arr2[0]` т.е. элемент `$arr3[0]` не создает для себя новый элемент а ссылается на элемент, который находится в `$arr2[0]`

Comment: @user299341 вот вам пример: `$arr2 = [0];
$arr3[0] = &$arr2[0];
$arr2[0] = '1';
var_dump($arr3);
var_dump($arr2);`